# Content Disposition in file Upload

Tags: java, content-disposition

Can anybody explain the concept of content-disposition? Physically, how it can be visualized ? Specifically in case of multi-part form-data.

Answer (score 0):

> In a regular HTTP response, the Content-Disposition response header is
>   a header indicating if the content is expected to be displayed inline
>   in the browser, that is, as a Web page or as part of a Web page, or as
>   an attachment, that is downloaded and saved locally.
>
> In a
>   multipart/form-data body, the HTTP Content-Disposition general header
>   is a header that can be used on the subpart of a multipart body to
>   give information about the field it applies to. The subpart is
>   delimited by the boundary defined in the Content-Type header. Used on
>   the body itself, Content-Disposition has no effect.
>
> The Content-Disposition header is defined in the larger context of
>   MIME messages for e-mail, but only a subset of the possible parameters
>   apply to HTTP forms and POST requests. Only the value form-data, as
>   well as the optional directive name and filename, can be used in the
>   HTTP context.

[MORE DETAILS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

Comment: please note when cite an other source