# React axios request to Django backend is empty

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, request, axios

So I am trying to send a set of scans (dcm files) to my Django server from my React App. The request should be as follows

```
    [
     {
         "scans": [
                     {"scan_image": <dcm file data>},
                     {"scan_image": <dcm file data>}
                  ],
         "name": "Set Name."
     },

    {
         "scans": [
                     {"scan_image": <dcm file data>},
                     {"scan_image": <dcm file data>}
                  ],
         "name": "Set Name."
     }
 ]
```

As shown the request payload is an array of objects. The objects are composed of two attributes, "scans" and "name" where scans attribute is an array of objects containing the data from dcm files. I read the data via the **readAsDataURL** method of the **FileReader** object instantiated as I iterate over the files selected by the user to upload.

Here is a log of the data gathered in the object that needed to be sent to the server.

[Log of the request containing the files to be uploaded to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN7LN.png)

Here is a snippet of the Axios request upon finishing the request object generation

```
axios({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_sets/',
        data: requestObject,
        method: 'post',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
        .then(res =>
            console.log("Success")
        )
        .catch(res =>
            console.log(res)
        )
```

Upon running that script, unfortunately, the request payload looks like this

```
[
    {
       "name":"5-AX T1-28522",
       "scans":[]
    },
    {
       "name":"3-AX T2 FSE-49954",
       "scans":[]
    },
    {
       "name":"4-AX FLAIR-60256",
       "scans":[]
    },
    {
       "name":"6-AX T1 POST-94928",
       "scans":[]
    }]
```

As you can see, the scans array that we logged and shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN7LN.png) here is empty.
Please help. I already have tried using **FormData** and changing the Axios request header to **multipart/form-data** with no luck there. Here is a link to the repo component in the project. I would be grateful if anyone was able to help. The function to look at is the **onChangeHandler**
https://github.com/omargaber/Lesion-Lab-UI/blob/master/src/Sidebar.jsx

Comment: did you check to make sure you are correctly setting the Content-Disposition?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004812/content-disposition-in-file-upload

Comment: I did but but the payload for some reason sends away the array of files data empty

Comment: I think sending an array to the backend requires converting it to a string, and when a JSON is stringified the file object will be lost